# Jquery combobox how to get value

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I'm trying to get the value from combobox-items, 
so i can give each a different function...

this is the combobox :

```
<select id="ComboBox" >
<option value="bios">Bioscopen </option>
<option value="dogs">HondenToiletten</option>
<option value="doctors">Huisartsen</option>
</select>
```

How can i see what is selected with jQuery and give them each another 
function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
var a =  $("#ComboBox").val();

alert (a);
```

then depending of received value run corresponding function

```
switch(a){
case : "bios" dosomething(); break
case : "doctors" dosomething_else(); break
default: break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this by binding on the change element of the select element, and then calling another function in the callback.  So maybe something like:

```
$('#ComboBox').change(function() { 
    var selectedItem = $(this).val();

    if (selectedItem === 'bios'){
        // Your code here, maybe another function call etc...
    } else if (selectedItem === 'dogs'){
        // More code
    }
    // and so on and so on
});
```

This isn't a super graceful way to handle this, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Something (rustic) like that, see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6N3sH/)

If you only want it to be launched when a change event happens, you can remove the `$(document).ready(....)` part

```
function bios() {
    alert("bios is selected");
}
function dogs() {
    alert("dogs coming");
}
function getVal(v) {
    switch(v) {
        case "bios":
            bios();
            break;
        case "dogs":
            dogs();
            break;
        default:
            alert('other');
            break;
    }
}
$('#ComboBox').change(function(){
    getVal($(this).val());
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    getVal($('#ComboBox').val());
});
```